# How to disable detection box in ImageAi

Tags: python, image-processing

We are working on point clouds and we take a photo each 5 seconds. Then, we need to blur some part of the photo (car, person etc ...) with ImageAI this part is done, i just want to remove/disable the bordering box of detected objects. I have put the option to disable names and percentages but i did not see something related to the bounding box.
If someone did this, that's would be cool !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what library are you using? OpenCV?

Comment: Yes ImageAi wich is using OpenCV

Comment: then try to find where ```cv2.rectangle(bounding box params)``` and delete the line hopefully bounding box will be removed.

Comment: Yes ! that was it ! put your comment as an answer then i can valid it ! Thanks again, you saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using OpenCV, then find where

```
cv2.reactangle(params)
```

and then delete the line, your bounding box will be removed.